# Inserir dados do Modal na tabela via Ajax PHP e JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, postgresql

Eu estou tentando inserir dados de uma tabela do meu Modal na tabela "pai" da minha página, basicamente eu tenho um modal, onde dei um select pra trazer os dados que não estão na tabela pai e o usuário inserir esses dados, o que acontece é que as requisições são feitas corretamente, porém o dado na tabela pai o valor retorna "null", aqui minha página html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="tablePrincipal">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Papéis funcionais do usuário
                        <button class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" name="Delete" value="Delete" id="deletar" ></button>
                        <button class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal"></button>
                    </th><br>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <a style="cursor: pointer;"><td><input type='checkbox' id="checkTodos__" /><b>  Identificador</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td></a>
                    <td><b>Nome</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
                $SQL = "SELECT ADR.IDROLE, ADR.NMROLE, ADR.CDROLE FROM ADUSERROLE ADUR, ADROLE ADR WHERE ADUR.CDROLE = ADR.CDROLE AND ADUR.CDUSER = '".$cduser."'";

                $SQL.=" ORDER BY ADR.IDROLE, ADR.NMROLE";

                $cur = $conn->execute($SQL);

                if($cur){
                    while(!$cur->EOF){
                        $linha = "<tbody><tr>";
                        $linha.= "<td> <input type='checkbox' />&nbsp;&nbsp;".$cur->fields['idrole']."</td>";
                        $linha.= "<td>".$cur->fields['nmrole']."</td>";
                        $linha.= "</tr></tbody>";
                        echo $linha;
                        $cur->MoveNext();

                        $cdrole = $cur->fields["cdrole"];
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>  

    <!-- Modal para exibição dos dados para adicionar na tabela pai -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Insira um novo registro</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <form id="formulario">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button class="fa fa-search" id="pesquisarDados" onclick="mostrarTabela();"></button>       
                        <label for="pesquisa">Pesquisar</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pesquisar" id="pesquisar" class="form-control" aria-describedby="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar">    
                        <table style="display: none;" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="mostraTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <a style="cursor: pointer;"><td><input type='checkbox' value="1" id="inputDado" name="inputDado" /><b>  Identificador</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td></a>
                                    <td><b>Nome</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>    
                            <tbody id="mostraDadosTable">

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>      
                </form>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="inserirDado" onclick="insereDado();">Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

esse formulário está dentro do meu Modal. E aqui meu JavaScript com Ajax, que faz a requisição pra minha página PHP onde tenho o INSERT no banco de dados:

```
<script>
        //seleciona os checkbox
        $("#checkTodos__").change(function () {
            $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });

        $("#checkTodos__").click(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        $("#inputDado").change(function () {
            $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });

        $("#inputDado").click(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        var checkTodos = $("#checkTodos");
        checkTodos.click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
            }
        });

        //limpa o campo de pesquisa do modal
        $('#Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#formulario').each(function() {
                $('#pesquisar').val(''); 
            });
        });

        //mostra a tabela no modal quando clica no Pesquisar
        function mostrarTabela(){
            document.getElementById('mostraTable').style.display = '';
        }

        //quando não tiver algo digitado na pesquisa, irá trazer todos os registros
        function pesquisaTodosDados(){
            $('#mostraDadosTable').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
            $('#formulario').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',   
                    url: 'actions.php',
                    data: { 
                        selecionaDados: "true",
                        iduser: '1185621'
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        //alert('sucesso');
                        for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                            //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
                            $('#mostraDadosTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="inputDado" name="inputDado" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'+data[i].idrole+'</td><td>'+data[i].nmrole+'</td></tr>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        //requisição assíncrona via Ajax e método Post para o arquivo getDados, e trás o que o usuário digitou na pesquisa
        function pesquisaDadosFiltrados(){
            $('#mostraDadosTable').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
            $('#formulario').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'getDados.php?pesquisar',
                    data: {
                        pesquisar: $('#pesquisar').val()
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        //Adicionando os registros filtrados na tabela
                        for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                            $('#mostraDadosTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="inputDado" name="inputDado" />&nbsp;&nbsp;' + data[i].idrole + '</td><td>' + data[i].nmrole + '</td></tr>', '');
                        };
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro na requisição');
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        //dispara as funções para pesquisar todos os dados ou somente os dados filtrados, conforme requisição
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#pesquisarDados').click(function(){
                pesquisa = $('#pesquisar').val()
                pesquisarDados(pesquisa);
            });

            function pesquisarDados(pesquisa){
                if (pesquisa == "") {
                    pesquisaTodosDados();
                } else {
                    pesquisaDadosFiltrados();
                }
            }
        });

        //insere dados conforme requisição for disparada no botão salvar do modal, ESSA FUNÇÃO É A QUE ESTOU COM PROBLEMAS, AO INSERIR OS DADOS RETORNADOS DA REQUISIÇÃO NA TABELA "PAI"

        function insereDado(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var arr = [];            
                $("input:checkbox[name=inputDado]:checked").each(function(){
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                    console.log('valor checkbox inputDado: ', arr);
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'insertDado.php',
                    data: {
                        insereDados : "true",
                        inputDado : arr
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('dado retornado: ', data);
                        console.log('valor checkbox inputDado no success: ', inputDado);
                        for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                            $('#tablePrincipal').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].idrole + '</td><td>' + data[i].nmrole + '</td></tr>');  
                        };
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro na requisição');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

e por fim, a minha página insertDado.php que faz o INSERT na tabela

```
<?php
require_once("../../global.php");
require_once("../specific/se_schulze.php");

$inputDado = $_POST['inputDado'];

function insereDados($inputDado){

    global $conn;

    $SQL = " INSERT INTO ADROLE (idrole, nmrole) VALUES ( '" . $inputDado . "', '" . $inputDado . "')";

    $cur = $conn->execute($SQL);

    $vetor = "";
    $registro = "";

    if($cur){  
        $registro["idrole"] = $cur->fields["idrole"];
        $registro["nmrole"] = $cur->fields["nmrole"];
        $vetor[] = $registro;
    }

    echo json_encode($vetor);
}

insereDados($inputDado);
```

?>

recebo meu "inputDado" por parâmetro porém acho que é ali onde está o erro. Alguém pode me ajudar? Já estou a 1 dia nesse problema e não consigo resolver

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85583/discussion-on-question-by-bruno-elias-de-souza-inserir-dados-do-modal-na-tabela) e pode prosseguir normalmente lá (por recomendação do sistema, de mais de vinte comentários seguidos no post) - Sobre a pergunta em si, tem muito código que não dá pra testar ou reproduzir, queira reduzir a funcionalidade a um [mcve] de forma que possamos ajudar. Capaz até que com o EMCV você localize o problema do código antes de nós.

Comment: é o link do primeiro comment --> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85583/discussion-on-question-by-bruno-elias-de-souza-inserir-dados-do-modal-na-tabela - mas mover no mesmo chat não dá, tem que entrar lá e escrever lá (o autor recebe notificação)